# Why don't or can't Windows archive programs list tar.gz files directly?

Tags: windows, tar

I see all Windows archive programs first list one tar file in tar.gz, not compressed files contained within.

So I double click the tar file and the program **extracts** the tar in a temporary folder and then list the files.

But in Linux I can easily list files inside tar.gz. I can't find any evidence if tar extracts the archive temporarily. Am I correct? If so, why don't they do like in Linux?

Answer (score 1):

Archiving consists of **two** steps:

- Combine many files into a single file
- optionally apply compression

With a `tar.gz` file, these layers of archiving are created by first combining the files and their Metadata into a **t**ape **ar**chive, then **gz**ipping this single file.

So two different programs (tar and gzip) are used to create the `.tar.gz` file, both of which can be used alone:

- Just gzip: Think of archived log files (eg `syslog.2.gz`)
- Just tar: Think of backup to a tape drive with built-in compression

When such a file is unpacked on linux via `tar -xz` you explicitly start both programs: `tar` is called and the `-z` option tells it to pipe through `gzip -d` (or friends like zcat, ...)

On Windows, when you just open the file, the decompression program has no way of knowing, if you just want to decompress the `tar` file or decompress it **and** unpack it. So it does the safe thing and decompresses only, allowing you to unpack later.

Comment: Yeah, I know how a tar.gz file is made, but again, for example, `tar tzf ...` lists files with no time. Why don't Windows arcivers do like that with whatever techniques like piping through or as such.

Comment: @DylanYi As I said: With the `tar -xz` command you **explicitly ask** for decompression **and** unpacking. WIth a doubleclick you don't have that liberty, so the application **doesn't know** if you want decompression only or both. It does the safe thing.